# how to use a form to navigate to specific query based on what is entered on the msgbox?

Tags: forms, ms-access, navigation, vba, messagebox

So I have a Access database with a table transaction.
On the table there is a column called profit filtered by month.

I have already made a few queries to calculate the total profit on monthly basis (eg. Jun,July,Aug)

So is it possible to create a form with a pop-up message box, and by enter a month number on the box and click, it will lead to a specific query?

I think it is a good idea but I know little about ACCESS programing so any comment are much appriciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use VBA's `InputBox` function to create the pop-up. If your queries already exist in the database, you could then use the results of that function to determine which query to open. For example:

```
Public Sub OpenExistingQuery()
  Dim intMonth As Integer
  intMonth = InputBox("Please enter a month number:", "Enter Month Number")
  DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryMonth" & intMonth, acViewNormal
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could use the results of the `InputBox` function to dynamically build a query, and then open it:

```
Public Sub OpenDynamicQuery()
  Const strQueryName As String = "qryDynamicMonth"

  Dim db As DAO.Database: Set db = CurrentDb
  Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
  Dim intMonth As Integer

  intMonth = InputBox("Please enter a month number:", "Enter Month Number")

  On Error Resume Next
  DoCmd.Close acQuery, strQueryName, acSaveNo
  DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, strQueryName
  On Error GoTo 0

  Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(strQueryName)
  qdf.SQL = "SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE your_monthnumber_column = " & intMonth
  qdf.Close

  DoCmd.OpenQuery strQueryName, acViewNormal

  Set qdf = Nothing
  Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Please note that the above functions are of the "quick-and-dirty" variety. They really need better error handling, sanitation of user input, etc. But hopefully you get the idea, and can take care of that on your own.